# How to read SVM results graph

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm

As part of my academic project regarding predicting success rate of an upcoming movie, I had to use SVM classifier for multiple classes in order to classify to which class a movie belongs. There are 5 classes :

```
Class 1 - Revenue < 0.5M
Class 2 - 0.5M < Revenue < 1M
Class 3 - 1M < Revenue < 50M
Class 4 - 50M < Revenue < 150M
Class 5 - Revenue > 150M
```

I get the results, and I'm able to calculate accuracy, but I have no idea how to read the following graph :

[image]

Can someone please explain, what do we see in this graph? How should I read it?

When we perform a binary classification, we can clearly see the separating hyperplane. However, in this case, how can we understand from this plot where the separation is?

Comment: Presumably the points are actuals and the shaded areas are predictive.  The scales are interesting as they naively suggest negative budgets and votes: perhaps they are some function of the true numbers and there is a minimum possible value

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.